# Java file delete on NFS drive

Tags: java, file, nfs, delete-file

I am trying to delete a file on a NFS drive.

I have had other problems manipulating files on remote drives such as moving a file - however i got around it by not using the conventional method i.e renameFile but instead properly using input and output streams.

However using the File.delete() returns false , and I have heard suggestions on using the apache commons io FileUtils class - however it just throws an IO exception.

Does anybody have any suggestions on a way to delete a file on a network mounted drive using java?

Comment: You should show some of your code, such as how you're using FileUtils.  Are you using the file you're deleting elsewhere?  Also, have you looked at deleteOnExit?

Comment: If you want people to anwser your questions in the future, please accept the answers for the questions you have asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it.

I hadnt close a previous buffered reader - meaning the delete couldnt get a lock on the file!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.

I had a bunch of .nfs files that were busy and couldn't delete. It was because I had a RandomFileAccess that I never closed. Once I closed it, the resource was no longer busy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).